# How do I set a custom input format for a field?

Tags: 8, entities

After using Drupal 7 for years, I am now handed a Drupal 8 site to do some editing. I have created a custom input format (*Plain HTML*), and I want to print this field with this input format in a custom template. How can I achieve this?

With `{{ content.field_mapka_markery }}`, it prints plain text. There is no choice to select my newly created input format in the *Manage display* settings. Why is that? In Drupal 7 there is always a new formatter,  but not so in Drupal 8.

I also tried `{{ content.field_mapka_markery|raw }}` or `.value`. `|raw` doesn't  work at all, and `.value` does the same as without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plain text format filters the text before storing, as far as I know. You need to store it as a formatted string. Then you can apply any filters you like.

Comment: No, input formats are used for rendering the field, not to alter the field value before storing it in the database.

Comment: It's not different from what done for the body field of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to create a new field with "Text - Formatted - Long" as default, which allowed me to set up my custom text format. Why is that not possible for plain text field I am not sure.